# Choosing variables for a semiparametric model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, aic, semiparametric

I am trying to create a semiparametric model for university (we were told it HAS to be semiparametric) and I have 11 response variables, some of them categorical and the rest continuous. In the simple glm case I could easily decide which variables to include with a stepAIC function in R, but now I not only have to decide which of them to include, but which should be part of the nonparametric component and which to the parametric one and I can not find any way to make the decission.

Is there a good way to approach this or to gain some intuition?

Thank you very much

Comment: [Even in the GLM case, stepwise regression has problems.](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/)

Comment: If you have binary variables, standard additive glm is already semiparametric. You are totally nonparametric in the additive component of the binary variable. Check mate. (Warning: your professor may not see it this way).